# Trouble with Smarty Template Engine

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I am Having Trouble with Smarty.
I need to do some calculations, Assignments, and Deletions in the `.tpl` file i.e. smarty.
But the problem I am facing is that when ever I do `{$idlist[$iSum+1]}` It gives Error. here $idlist is an array and `$iSum` is a an Integer.
It works fine with `{$idlist[$iSum]}` or `{$idlist[3]}` but gives error in `{$idlist[$iSum+1]}` 
What must be the syntax to run some statement like this `{$idlist[$iSum+1]}` ?

Comment: did u try `{$idlist[($iSum)+1]}`

Comment: @BhuvanRikka That Doesn't Work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
{assign var="iSum" value=$iSum+1}
```

since you also want to use mathematical operation template side, Also read smarty **[math function](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.math.tpl)**